# Is using tabs for navigation a violation of the ARIA specification?

Tags: html, tabs, single-page-application, nav, wai-aria

The current title is as carefully reworded by somebody else. I could rephrase it as *Do ARIA specs allow the use of tabs-based implementation of a navigation menu?*, just in case it makes things clearer to other readers.

---

[*§3.22 Tabs*](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#tabpanel) from [*WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1*](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1) reads

> Tabs are a set of layered sections of content, known as tab panels, that display one panel of content at a time. Each tab panel has an associated tab element, that when activated, displays the panel. The list of tab elements is arranged along one edge of the currently displayed panel, most commonly the top edge.

This doesn't seem to exclude that one could use tabs for navigation, i.e. for the elements in a `<nav>`. I think one example of a website that does so are GitHub profile pages ([example](https://github.com/Aster89?tab=repositories)).

On the other hand, the [examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/tabs/tabs-1/tabs.html) from *WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1* use `<button role="tab" ...>` in a `<div role="tablist" ...>`, and the selected tab doesn't persist across page refreshes. From a later part of the document, I read:

> When a tabbed interface is initialized, one tab panel is displayed and its associated tab is styled to indicate that it is active.

which makes me think it's the intention of WAI-ARIA to have a specific tab panel be selected when the page is refreshed, ignoring which one is selected right before refreshing.

And this does seem to exclude that one could use tabs for navigation, unless one is happy that the navigation state is wiped out every time the page is refreshed.

So my question is two-fold:

- Does using tabs for navigation violate some ARIA principle (e.g.  accessibility)?
- If that's the case, then what are those tab-like things I see on GitHub profiles, if not tabs? Or is it just that GitHub is designed in a way that is not ARIA-compliant?

Comment: As currently written, this question is off-topic because what constitutes "good practice" or "bad practice" is a matter of opinion. If you edit this question to be about compliance with a specification (e.g. ARIA) then it would be on-topic because compliance with a published specification is an objective matter.

Comment: @TylerH what about it now?

Comment: Adding essentially "about ARIA" to the title is not a sufficient edit in that regard, no. I will take some time to revise your question so that it focuses on objective/on-topic matters.

Comment: @TylerH _WAI-ARIA_ is written 3 times in the body of my question. Doesn't that convey that I'm interested in an answer as regards that standpoint?

Comment: Yes, but  the question you were actually, explicitly asking was "is this bad design/undesirable/edgy". These are irrelevant to ARIA compliance. Someone could legitimately hold the view that ARIA's spec itself is bad design, undesirable, or edgy... but their answer wouldn't particularly help you if you want to comply with ARIA's spec. That is why questions on Stack Overflow must be objective; ask about complying with ARIA's spec specifically and you will only get answers that are guaranteed to help not only you, but also anyone else who has the same question in the future.

Comment: @TylerH, I guess _volution_ is a typo for _violation_? Btw, I was going to change the title to _Do ARIA specs allow the use of tabs-based implementation of a navigation menu?_ Would that be good?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo from copying/moving words around, thanks. And yes, that would be a good title

Answer (score 2):

The [tab pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tabpanel) is a nice way to save screen real estate without having to navigate to new pages.  It's essentially a container that lets you display different content depending on which tab is selected.  It's almost like an iframe.

Using it for navigation would be a little odd because what [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions) would you use?  Navigation elements should be [links](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#link) but tab elements have a role of [tab](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#tab).  Selecting a link implies you can go back to where you previously were by selecting the browser's "back" button.  Selecting a tab does not have such implications.

The example on github, if you're talking about the "overview", "repositories", "projects", and "packages" elements, those actually take you to a new url so using links is correct.  The "back" button takes me back to the previous view.  Those elements are not implemented as tabs.

Comment: I'm not totally convinced. You say that _Those elements are not implemented as tabs_, yet which one is selected is encoded in the URL with a trailining `?tab=whatever`, so whoever wrote that code thought of them as tabs, don't you think?

Comment: They're implemented as links using the '?' as a parameter so they can visually stylize the page to make a tab look selected.  But since they're links, I can use the browser "back" button to go back to the previous view.  A true `tab` widget would not have the "back" behavior.